# sync Facebook Post Likes and Post in Website Likes

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I Apologise if I´m repeating a topic. I know this question is asked before but there is no clear answer about the solution. I´m looking to unify Facebook post likes and Website post url (related to that Facebook post) likes. There´s a way to do this?

Perhaps a library, code, book, tutorial, something.

Thanks!

Comment: you simply share the url of your website post on facebook

Comment: Uf, did you have a working example? I really appreciate your help but in my case did not work with this simple approach. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to do the same thing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615717/facebook-graph-api-like-share-comment-relative-to-object-instead-of-url turns out that you can't currently refer to the facebook post this way. You can refer to the page/user or the attachments in the post but you cannot refer to the post itself.I submitted a bug report on facebook developer page